# Puedo pasar un shortcode como atributo de otro shortcode? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy haciendo un shortcode que me permita mostrar solo x información a ciertos usuarios, el shortcode recibe un atributo (que seria el email del usuario), lo compara y si es igual realiza x cosa, pero no me va...

```
    add_shortcode('verPago', 'sh_verPago' );

    function sh_verPago( $attr, $content = null ){

        extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'correo' => 'sinEmail' ), $attr ) );

        if ( $correo == "ejemplo@gmail.com" && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
        return $content;

    return "";
}
```

Y así es como coloco el shortcode en un widget de texto por el backend:

```
[verPago correo="[su_user field='user_email']"]
Si eres ejemplo@gmail.com
[/verPago]
```

En donde [su_user field="user_email"] es otro shortcode que me ofrece un plugin instalado, si coloco directamente un email, si que funciona, pero pasandole este shortcode no va...

Answer (score 2):

Esto es porque los shortcodes no procesan otros shortcodes como parámetro de forma automática, pero puedes hacer que tu código lo haga si usas `do_shortcode().`

deberás reemplazar `$correo == ...` por `do_shortcode($correo) == ...`

Aquí está la explicación detallada (en inglés): https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes